# MySQL DB Trigger Insert after cost linked to id

Tags: mysql, database, triggers

first Trigger I created.

I have two tables, student and cost.

If I insert a new student I want to automatically insert a cost row for this student in the table cost and insert the corresponding student id to the cost.

I don´t know how I can link the student id to the cost...

```
CREATE TRIGGER `add_cost` AFTER INSERT ON `student` FOR EACH ROW INSERT INTO cost (amount) VALUES (2000)
```

Thanks everybody!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your insert statement please use just:

```
NEW.{primary_key}
```

from related table(in your case student). If your primary is id this should looks like:

```
NEW.id
```

NEW is created after row is inserted and contain all inserted values + PK after insert.
Finally your query should looks like below:

```
INSERT INTO cost (student_id, amount) VALUES (NEW.id, 2000)
```

You can find more info on http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html